# Django: don't cache particular view?

Tags: django

As per the title...

Is there a way I can force a particular view (actually a particular JSON-formatted set of results, that will be served to Ajax queries) NEVER to cache in Django?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be sure, decorate it with `@never_cache`:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def myview(request):
    # ...
```

As in [The per-view cache](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Django does not cache views unless you specify a [per-view cache](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache).

If you have problems with (cached) Ajax responses, try to add a timestamp to your URL:

e.g. /my_view?ts=23432453453

So you can be sure that your browser does not cache the Ajax responses.